# How to search within the nested array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to search a for a string say for example "hello" within 'name' in array of objects. The data structure is like the one below,

```
[{name:'hello', value: 'value', children: [{ name:'world', value: 'something'}]},
{name:'somename', value: 'value2', children: [{name: 'hello', value: 'value3', children: [{name: 'anothername', value: 'value4'}]},
{name: 'new', value: 'value5'}];
```

So from the above mentioned data structure, if the search query is say 'hello' i want to check through 'name' field of each object. also check within children 'name' field of each object. Some object may or may not have children and nested children too. I want to retreive the objects that have matched the search query.

For example if my search query is 'hello' then the expected output is as below,

```
[{name:'hello', value: 'value', children: [{ name:'world', value: 'something'}]},
{name:'somename', value: 'value2', children: [{name: 'hello', value: 'value3', children: [{name: 'anothername', value: 'value4'}]},
```

i have tried using the below search method but that doesnot search within children and nested children.

```
search = (query, listitems => {
    if (!query) {
        return listitems;
    }
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    const results = [];
    let counter;
    let childcounter;
    listitem.forEach((listitem) => {
        counter = 0;
        childcounter = 0;
        if (listitem['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1)
        {
            counter++;
            if (listitem.children)
            {
                listitem.children.forEach ((child) => {
                    if (child['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1)
                    childcounter++;
                });

            }
            listitem.counter = counter;
            listitem.childcounter = childcounter;
            results.push(listitem);
        }
        return result
    });
```

How can i do it. could someone help me with it. Thanks.